# Unable to bind data from factory in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have no clue what I am doing wrong...
App here

```
var traccApp = angular.module('traccApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngResource'
]);
```

factory here

```
traccApp.factory('TraccData', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('app/data/tracks/:id', {id: '@id'});
    }]);
```

Controller here

```
traccApp.controller('newsFeedController', ['$scope', 'TraccData',

    function($scope, TraccData) {

        $scope.tracks = TraccData;
  }]);
```

View here

```
<div ng-controller="newsFeedController">
 <p><strong>Artist:</strong> {{tracks.artist}}</p>
 </div>
```

json object here

```
  {
      "id": 1,
      "artist":"Lorum Ipsum",
      "title":"test tes ",
      "genre":"lorum ipsum genre",
      "cover":"file"
}
```

Nothing is showing up in my view? Nothing seems to be getting binded and im getting no errors either..

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the model:

```
<div ng-controller="newsFeedController" ng-model="tracks">
    <p><strong>Artist:</strong> {{tracks.artist}}</p>
 </div>
```

Note however that it is a good practice to have a dot in your model.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only getting the resource object without executing any request :

```
$scope.anArtist = ''
$scope.tracks = TraccData.query(function() {
  $scope.anArtist = $scope.tracks[0];
});
```

And in your markup :

```
<p><strong>Artist:</strong> {{anArtist.artist}}</p>
```